# What’s the equivalent of Range.Value from VBA in excel for google sheets?

Tags: excel, vba, google-apps-script

I’ve made a sales form in a google sheet and want to copy the data to a database sheet. In excel, I’d use `Range.Value(“!Sheet1:A1)=Range.Value(“!Sheet2:A2)`.

How would I apply this in Google Sheets?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Why don't you record a macro in Google sheets to see?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike VBA, Google Sheets script uses `getRange` to navigate to the cell,  `getValue` to get the value and `setValue` to set the value of the cell. You may use these for your purpose.

Below is a small function that I have quickly written to get you started. It sets the value in A18 of sheet1 by getting the value from B18. You may modify it to suit your purpose.

```
function myFunction() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('A18').setValue(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('B18').getValue());

}
```

Comment: I’m getting a type error: Cannot call method “getrange” of null. What would you suggest?

Comment: Have you set the sheet name? Like 'Sheet1' in my function. Can you share your code perhaps?